# How to turn on app notification badges in Aviate launcher?

Tags: launcher

I have a Galaxy S3,  and I just installed the Aviate launcher. For the most part, I really like it, but I have one quibble - I can't work out how to turn on app notification badges. I've found [this page](https://uk.help.yahoo.com/kb/aviate/notification-badges-aviate-sln24301.html?impressions=true) but the solution there doesn't work for me - pressing and holding on the home screen doesn't bring up a settings button.